Problema al ordenar arrays con ciclo for
Tengo una materia donde vemos problemas de programación, pero en vez de ponerlos en forma de código hacemos unos cuadros, el profesor siempre se maneja con Python, pero para yo entender el tema que estamos viendo ahora quería ponerlo en JavaScript y ver como se resuelve.
El enunciado es algo simple y es que hay que ordenar el array, la cosa es que no se puede usar un método de array como push o algo así para ir acomodando los elementos, sino que hay que ir cambiándoles el valor como se muestra en el código que hice, pero ahora el problema es que no se donde poner el console.log() para que me de el array ordenado, también otro problema es que creo que el código no esta funcionando.
Este es uno de los cuadros que digo que el hace para esta materia, el código de al lado ignórenlo, soy yo intentando hacer el cuadro en código, si me pueden ayudar con esto seria de muchísima ayuda.



let vec1 = [34, 5, 66, 77, 88, 23, 32];
let auxNum = 0;
let auxInd = 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    for (let j = i + 1; i <=7; i++){
        if(vec1[i] > vec1[j]){
            auxNum = vec1[j];
            vec1[j] = vec1[i];
            vec1[i] = auxInd;
            
        }
        console.log(vec1[j])
    } 
}
console.log(vec1)




lo que pides no se puede ... a pesar de ser simple el planteamiento tu profesor hace esto e python y difiere de javascript ... no es lo mismo por ende el codigo debe sufrir cambios si o si para poder alcansar el objetivo que indicas ...

y como seria el codigo en python? me podrias dar un ejemplo?

ese no es el objetivo del sitio... si tienes algun problema con un codigo con gusto te ayudamos ... pero hacerte un codigo desde 0 no es correcto ...

con la estructura de codigo que tienes, el console.log no hara lo que esperas ... por ende no hay una hubicacion correcta dentro de tu codigo para colocarlo y obtener el resultado que esperas... solo cambiando el codigo javascript y haciendo adecuaciones y colocando el console.log al final podras obtener el resultado esperando ...

muchas gracias, perdona las molestias

como ya hay 2 respuestas, aquí te va una sugerencia cuando no entiendas algún algoritmo, en YouTube hay varios videos de estructuras de datos, la búsqueda sería: "algoritmo método de la burbuja explicación", si deseas más contenido, busca en inglés: "algorithm bubble sort method explanation". Lo mismo cuando quieras algún ejemplo de código, en Google, Ecosia, Bing: "método de la burbuja ejemplo python". Intenta, experimenta, si hay errores, vienes al sitio y detallas la pregunta con los intentos que tuviste, de este modo, las chances de obtener respuesta aumentan notablemente. Saludos.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

El console.log para ver el array ordenado si o si debe ir al final de la ejecucion si quieres mostrar el metodo final ordenado, ojo que fue necesario actualizar el script...
Segun la tarea:


let vec1 = [34, 5, 66, 77, 88, 23, 32];
let auxNum;
let auxInd;

for (let i = 0; i < vec1.length - 1; i++) {
    auxInd = i;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < vec1.length; j++) {
        if (vec1[j] < vec1[auxInd]) {
            auxInd = j;
        }
    }
    if (auxInd !== i) {
        auxNum = vec1[i];
        vec1[i] = vec1[auxInd];
        vec1[auxInd] = auxNum;
    }
}

console.log(vec1);



Explicación del Código:

Inicialización del Array y Variables: Inicializamos vec1 con los valores dados y declaramos auxNum y auxInd.

Primer Bucle (i): Recorremos el array desde el primer hasta el penúltimo elemento.

Inicialización del Índice del Mínimo: Asignamos el índice del elemento actual a auxInd.

Segundo Bucle (j): Recorremos el array desde el elemento siguiente al actual hasta el último elemento.

Comparación y Actualización del Índice del Mínimo: Si encontramos un elemento menor que el actual mínimo (vec1[auxInd]), actualizamos auxInd al índice de este elemento.

Intercambio de Elementos: Si encontramos un nuevo mínimo, intercambiamos los valores de vec1[i] y vec1[auxInd].

Resultado: El console.log(vec1) al final del código muestra el array ordenado.


Actualmente:
Ten en cuenta que lo anterior no es la forma moderna en que se haria... en realidad en lenguaje de programacion con esto obtendrias el mismo resultado.


let vec1 = [34, 5, 66, 77, 88, 23, 32];

vec1.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(vec1);



El Método sort(): Utilizamos sort() con una función de comparación (a, b) => a - b. Esta función asegura que el array se ordene en orden ascendente:

Si a - b es negativo, a se sitúa antes que b.
Si a - b es positivo, a se sitúa después que b.
Si a - b es cero, se mantiene el orden original entre a y b.


muchas gracias por tu ayuda pero no es lo que busco, del codigo no hay que modificar nada que no sea el console.log o unos pequeños detalles, como ya dije es para una tarea y se debe hacer de cierta manera, se que hay metodos mas cortos, aparte en el if debe compararte vec1[i] y vec1[j] como hace mi profesor

El método de la burbuja, es una forma bastante simple de ordenar un array. Vas comparando los elementos y sin el elementoA es mayor al elementoB se cambian de lugar.
Para cambiar de lugar es necesario utilizar una variable auxiliar
auxNum = vec1[j];
vec1[j] = vec1[i];
vec1[i] = auxNum;
// vec1[i] = auxInd; //Tu tienes esto, que es incorrecto, porque la variable auxiliar es auxNum

Habitualemete para recorrer un array, se hace desde el índice cero hasta el largo-1,no obstante, en este caso se hace hasta largo-2 por 2 razones:

Los 2 for tienen el sentido comparar cada número con los otros números restantes (todas las posibilidades). Al llegar al último número, éste ya ha sido comparado todas las veces contra el resto de los números, por lo que no es enserio realizar su comparación
Como el segundo for es j=i+1, cuando i es el último número j rebasará el índice. Por lo que conviene acotar el largo de i

Entonces en un array de largo 7, el primero for debe ir desde 0 a 5:
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) //así debe ser
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) //así lo tienes tu

Luego el segundo for da a lugar a todas las combinacioes posible, este comienza desde i+1, porque comparas el número vec[i] contra los siguientes (si fuera j=i estarás comparando consigo mismo). El segundo for tiene que ser:
for (let j = i + 1; j <=6; j++) //así es
for (let j = i + 1; i <=7; i++) //así lo tienes tu
//                  ↑      ↑ esos debes ser j 


Aquí el código:


let vec1 = [34, 5, 66, 77, 88, 23, 32];
let auxNum = 0;

console.log(`vec1[]   :`, vec1.toString())
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for (let j = i + 1; j <7; j++){
        if(vec1[i] > vec1[j]){
            auxNum = vec1[j];
            vec1[j] = vec1[i];
            vec1[i] = auxNum;
            
        }
    } 
    console.log(`pasada ${i+1} :`, vec1.toString())
}




Un comentario final: A veces el pseudocódigo trae más problemas de los que soluciona, por ejemplo esta notación
Para i=1 hasta 6 (N-1)

Comienza con i=1 porque las personas normalmente cuentan desde el 1, pero el equivalente de este pseudocódigo a cualquier lenguaje cuyos índices de array comiencen en cero es
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) 

que es equivalente a
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++)

